# CakePHP model->find seems to be ignoring the conditions

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

In my Jobs controller I have this statement under the index() function:

```
$this->Job->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Job.completed' => '0', 'Job.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
$this->set('jobs', $this->paginate());
```

This should show all incomplete jobs for the currently logged in user under the $jobs variable (when accessed from a view). However, I'm getting all incomplete jobs for every user.

```
$this->Auth->user('id'); //returns correct user ID for logged in user
```

Have I missed something?
I've just revisited CakePHP after months of absence and I fear I may have to relearn some of the basics.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:) welcome back to cake

`$this->Job->find()` will return an array.. it doesn't modify the pagination. if you do :

```
$jobs = $this->Job->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Job.completed' => '0', 'Job.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
pr($jobs);
```

you will see that the conditions are correct..

to add conditions to the pagination you must change the [pagination property](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html), something like:

```
 $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('Job.completed' => '0', 'Job.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
        'limit' => 10
    );
 $this->set('jobs', $this->paginate());
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah, thanks for this. The moment you mentioned it, it all came rushing back to me haha! Lifesaver!